# Modal field empty after form submit

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have modal to submit comment entered by the user. But when the user enters submit button, the form-backing-object reaches the post end point but the field entered using the modal is empty.

```
           <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Comment for approval</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                    <textarea rows="5"
                                              placeholder="Comment..."
                                              th:field="*{processApproveComment}"
                                              th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.processApproveComment}"
                                              class="form-control"
                                            name="processApproveComment">
                                                     </textarea>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                    <button type="submit" formaction="/release/process"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                                        class="btn btn-info" role="button">
                                    Approve
                                </button>
                                <input th:type="hidden" th:field="*{processApproveComment}"
                                       th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.processApproveComment}"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The place where modal is called is

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/release/process"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                                class="btn btn-info" role="button">
                            Approve
                        </button>
```

The flow is:  after the form is complete, the user clicks "Approve" button, which triggers the modal, the user then enters the comment and presses "Approve" (from the modal) and the form is submitted.

Could someone PLEASE suggest what is wrong here as I am not receiving just the processApproveComment (which is set using the modal) when other properties from the parent form are available.

The post endpoint is :

```
    @PostMapping("/release/process")
    public String releaseProcess(Principal principal,
                                 Model model,
                                 @ModelAttribute("answeredQuestionnaire") AnsweredQuestionnaire answeredQuestionnaire){
//   answeredQuestionnaire does not have processApproveComment, but all others are available.
}
```

**Update:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                    <textarea rows="5"
                                              placeholder="Comment..."
                                              th:field="*{processApproveComment}"
                                              th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.processApproveComment}"
                                              class="form-control"
                                            name="processApproveComment">
                                                     </textarea>
                                    <button type="submit" formaction="/release/process"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
                                            class="btn btn-info" role="button">
                                        Approve
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because button tag not in form tag

1. Move button tag to form tag

Comment: Sorry it didn't help, I moved inside form tag in modal as in update.

Comment: Can you show me your thymleaf code?

Comment: I have already added the code where the modal is triggered. The form was working correctly without modal, now just the modal part is not working

Comment: in action form, replace to th:action = "/release/process" and add th:object="${answeredQuestionnaire}"  in attribute form tag

Comment: th:action = "@{/release/process}"  th:object="${answeredQuestionnaire}" added, but it didn't help